Mean Index of deprivation score
I've created a python function which can return a subset of the 2019 Index of Multiple Deprivation scores representing the LSOA areas within a defined radius of a certain latitude and longitude.
Here's an example:

I want to report the median IncDec number as that. Might sound obvious, but that is simply the median of the decile metrics of those LSOAs, right?

I will do. I think in hindsight I should have considered whether the mean of a decile is even a thing when the whole point of a decile is to bin the data in the first place. But you're right it is clumsy thinking.
